# Show multiple checkbox value in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is when I tick a checkbox the value should show in a text box. But with the below code I can't show value in more than one checkbox. It overwrites the old one.

```js
$('#multiselect-drop input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#results').val(this.value);
  } else {
    $('#results').val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="results">
<div id="multiselect-drop">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Testing the textbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Testing 2 the textbox">
</div>
```

So what I want is, show all checked values in the text box with comma-separated. Anyone can help?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, I did.
$('#multiselect-drop input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $li = $('<li></li>');
      $li.text(this.value);
      $("#txtsessions").val($('#results').html().replace(/(<\/li>)/ig, ", ").replace(/(<li>)/ig, "")   );
      $('#results').append($li);
     
  }
  else {
    $('li:contains('+this.value+')', '#results').remove();
  }
});
@DylanLandry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get all checkboxes rather than just the one that is checked:

```js
var $inputs = $('#multiselect-drop input');
var $results = $('#results');
$inputs.change(function() {
  var values = $inputs.filter(':checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(',');
  $results.val(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="results">
<div id="multiselect-drop">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Testing the textbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Testing 2 the textbox">
</div>
```